# SharePoint Web part vs ASP.NET web part

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Can some one give me the difference between a SharePoint web part and an ASP.NET web part. I found very little information describing the differences.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a short comparison at http://weblogs.asp.net/sbehera/archive/2008/07/09/asp-net-2-0-web-part-vs-sharepoint-based-web-part.aspx

Answer (score 7):

[MSDN - Choosing Between ASP.NET 2.0 Web Parts and Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Web Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153523(office.12).aspx#WSS3ASPNET20WebParts_ChoosingtherRightapproachApproach)

You should create ASP.NET 2.0 Web Parts whenever you can. However, there are a few exceptions where using SharePoint-based Web Parts might offer advantages.. The following table provides a decision matrix to help you choose the best option depending on your business needs.

**Create a custom ASP.NET 2.0 Web Part**

- For most business needs.
- To distribute your Web Part to sites
  that run ASP.NET 2.0 or SharePoint
  sites.
- When you want to reuse one or more
  Web Parts created for ASP.NET 2.0
  sites on SharePoint sites.
- To use data or functionality provided
  by Windows SharePoint Services 3.0.
  For example, you are creating a a Web
  Part that works with site or list
  data.

**Create a SharePoint-based Web Part**

- When you want to migrate a set of Web
  Parts using the SharePoint-based Web
  Part infrastructure to Windows
  SharePoint Services 3.0.
- To create cross page connections.
- To create connections between Web
  Parts that are outside of a Web Part
  zone.
- To work with client-side connections
  (Web Part Page Services Component).
- To use a data-caching infrastructure
  that allows caching to the content
  database.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i got, SharePoint WebPart overrides ASP.NET WebPart

1. to to persist its data inside the content database of SharePoint Foundation
2. you can design for and use an ASP.NET Web Part in SharePoint, but not vice versa.
3. SPF WebParts supports backward compatibility, cross-page connections, conns between WebParts that are outside of a zone, client-side connections (Web Part Pages  Services Component), data caching (incl. to database)
4. they use differing WebPartManager (e.g. SPWebPartManager) and WebPartZone objects, so you can't easy copy WebParts Pages from ASP.NET to SharePoint, but rather export WebParts

Most of that you find on ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415560.aspx