# Where can I find a comparison of what changed between the different versions of Microsoft's ASP.Net Web Parts?

Tags: asp.net, web-parts, .net-framework-version

I realize that I could manually go through the documentation of each object for each version of the .Net framework, but that would be less than ideal. Where can I find a table or outline or some other kind of summary on what changed with the different versions of [ASP.Net Web Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of web parts, ASP.NET  Web Parts and SharePoint Web Parts:

http://spandothers.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/asp-net-web-parts-v-sharepoint-web-parts/

[SharePoint Web part vs ASP.NET web part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266374/sharepoint-web-part-vs-asp-net-web-part)

Comment: I'm talking about ASP.Net Web Parts in this case, I've updated my question.